# TSQL only pull data if another date field is the previous business day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**1)** I'm need only to pull data if the the openddate is equal to the PrevBiz date.   I think the where/and statement would be `Openddate = PrevBiz`, but not sure.  It wasn't working for me and could be because the date format isn't matching.  Any Suggestions?

```
   DECLARE @TODAY       DATE    = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @PREVFIRST  CHAR(8) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0), 112)
DECLARE @PREVLAST   CHAR(8) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), -1), 112) 
        DECLARE @PREVBIZ    CHAR(12) = DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(CHAR(12), @TODAY,112))
                            WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN -2
                            WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN -3
                            ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT(CHAR(12), @TODAY, 112)))

          SELECT TOP 10
          CURRENTDATE       =@TODAY, 
          FIRST_OF_MONTH    =@PREVFIRST,
          LASTDAY_OFMONTH   =@PREVLAST,
          PREVBIZ           =@PREVBIZ,

           DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(DATE, @TODAY,101))
            WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN -2
            WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN -3
            ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT(DATE, @TODAY, 101))) AS PREVIOUSBIZDATE,

          OpendDate 

          FROM [USBI_DW].[USBI].[vw_NameAddressBase]
          where IsCurrent = 1
```

Here's my results:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @TODAY datetime   = convert(date,GETDATE())
declare @PREVBIZ   datetime =  DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@TODAY)
                            WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN -2
                            WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN -3
                            ELSE -1 END,@TODAY)
declare @iToday int = convert(nvarchar(8),@TODAY, 112)
      , @iPrevBiz int = convert(nvarchar(8),@PREVBIZ, 112)

select top 10
      CURRENTDATE       =@iToday,
      PREVBIZ           =@iPrevBiz,
      OpendDate 

from [USBI_DW].[USBI].[vw_NameAddressBase]
where IsCurrent = 1
and OprendDate = @iPrevBiz
```

hope your view contains int date attribute ( because of DateWarehouse specific)